# Why does changing the name of a unit test in Google Test somehow makes me unable to open a file?

Tags: c++, googletest

## The problem

I'm trying to test a C++ function using [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) that reads a text file into a vector of strings that delimits by whitespace. The implementation details are not causing the error to my knowledge since using any generic file open triggers the error.

The issue I ran into is that I opened the file for the first time under the test name 'TestReadFile', and since that action, I am unable to open the file in any other test with a different name. I do suspect that it has something to do with the name, because when I change a test's name to 'TestReadFile,' no matter if the code is different, it is able to read the file successfully.

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "words.h"
#include <fstream>

TEST(CommonWordsTests, TestReadFile) {
  std::ifstream fin;
  fin.open("test.txt");
  EXPECT_TRUE(fin.is_open());
  fin.close();
}

TEST(CommonWordsTests, NotTestReadFile) {
  std::ifstream fin;
  fin.open("test.txt");
  EXPECT_TRUE(fin.is_open());
  fin.clear();
  fin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  fin.close();
}
```

Upon running this code, the first test (TestReadFile) passes, whereas the second test (NotTestReadFile) fails, returning the following output:

```
Failure
Value of: fin.is_open()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
```

## What I tried

Originally, I thought this was due to me not closing the file, so I appended `fin.close()` and

```cpp
  fin.clear();
  fin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
```

to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Edit: I downloaded GoogleTest into my local directory using CMake but one could also clone Google Test from https://github.com/google/googletest into the local directory, and the include statements would work fine.

Let me know if this is still not reproducible.

Comment: Added an edit to make it more clear how to reproduce.

Comment: Can't reproduce. https://godbolt.org/z/x7M7Gf8z7

Comment: Have you tried reordering the two tests?